# Book about a dog who protects his family from a werewolf

Tags: story-identification, books, werewolf

I'm trying to remember the title and author of a book I read years ago. It's about a dog, something like a German Shepherd with a name like "Thor", who lives with a normal family. When a friend/cousin/uncle returns from a trip abroad the dog realises he's a danger to the family and tries to protect them.

The really interesting thing about the book is that it's written from the dog's perspective, in particular the way he perceives his place in the family as part of a pack.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The book is ["Thor: A Novel"](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3326984-thor) (hardcover) by [Wayne Smith](http://www.goodreads.com/author/show/298425.Wayne_Smith). The [paper](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/542284.Thor)[back](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11352167-thor) and [Kindle](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10795384-thor) editions just list the title as "Thor":

> Thor is a German shepherd belonging to a typical suburban family,
>   wise, trustworthy, and tirelessly devoted to his human "pack." Then
>   Uncle Ted comes to live with Thor's owners. And the terror begins. For
>   Ted is no longer fully human, and only Thor can detect the Bad Thing
>   lurking within Uncle Ted. Only Thor can sense the horror he is
>   helpless to communicate. And only Thor can defeat that horror.

It was even made into a movie: [*Bad Moon*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115610/) (1996). Although I don't know how closely the movie follows the book. The summaries make it sound like it's told more from the perspective of Uncle Werewolf than that of the dog.